# web.config - Invalid configuration data for the page?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Created a Web Application in ASP.NET (c# language), than Build -> Published to Desktop, moved all files and folders to the `./test` directory of the root of my `localhost`, than go to `localhost/test/Default.aspx`, and get this error message:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.

Points to this bit of code within web.config:

```
<section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
```

Actually, more digging reveals this:

> There is a duplicate
>   'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section
>   defined

Can I just define this in the root web.config file?  Or is it safe to remove it altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this entry is defined in machine.config, then it's considered duplicate. Either remove this entry from web.config or add a remove sentence before.

```
<remove name="scriptResourceHandler/>
```

Comment: When I was upgrading a web service from .net 3.5 to 4, I completely removed this section, along with all services listed under sectionGroup "webServices" (jsonSerialization, profileService, authenticationService and roleService). Everything is still working.